Cannot drop Table, receive "ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"
I have a mariadb (10.6.16-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) database hosted on Ubuntu.
In my application I am using Hangfire for background tasks.
After an update of my application it was not starting anymore. The reason was, that Hangfire was not able to start. I can't remember the exact error, but it was database related, so I started to drop all Hangfire related tables (they will be created automatically from the application, when they do not exist).
There are some tables, that I am not able to drop (HangfireHash, HangfireJob, HangfireJobQueue, HangfireSet, HangfireState). I receive the error:
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

What I already did so far without success:

Restarting the server
Stopping the application
SHOW OPEN TABLES where I can see, that no one is in use
show processlist; to be sure, that only one process (my current session) is accessing the database
show status where variable_name = 'threads_connected', to be sure, that there is onle one thread connected
Increasing the lock timeout set innodb_lock_wait_timeout=600;
Looking for blocking transactions with SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
Force to ignore foreign keys (SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;) before dropping the table
Doing a backup of the database with mysqldump, droping the database. Remove all Hangfire tables from the dump and restoring the database. This will result in an error message, when hangfires tries to recreate the tables: : 'Table 'HangfireJob' already exists'
Deleteing all Hangfire* files in /var/lib/mysql/[DB_NAME], which also results in the error message 'Table 'HangfireJob' already exists' after a restart of the application.

How can I get completly rid of these Hangfire* tables in my database, so that they can be recreated?

15.1 is the MariaDB client version. What does select version() show? Don't play with MariaDB files directly. There's a drop database command for a reason.

@danblack, thanks, I have edited the version in the post. Like I wrote, I tried to do that with drop database without success. It is a private project, so I did a backup of the complete virtual machine before messing arround with files

@Chris Did you manage to solve the problem? I got exactly the same issue with MariaDB+Hangfire. Even the table set is almost the same - Hash, Job, JobQueue and State.
